# Calling stored function using user input variable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Newbie here. I'm building a web app in c# that uses a database to display results via a variable contained within a dropdown.

So far, I have a procedure that looks like the following;

```
USE [energyexpenditure]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[getbysID] @schoolID int

as

select *
from energyInvoices
where schoolID=@schoolID
order by dateFiled;
```

My question is, does/can "schoolID" represent a variable from the webapp? For example, the user selects a school from the dropdown, which sends a variable of "schoolID=1" to represent a specific school. Does SQL interpret that schoolID properly? Or should I be doing something differently?

Edit: Apologies for the terrible format here, I'm very new to this.

Comment: Your have the c# tag, but I see no c# code. Your question is unclear too.

Comment: The schoolID is int so no problem. how do you call the procedure from c# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your C# application will indeed be able to assign a value to this parameter.

Assuming an `SqlCommand` instance named `cmd`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("schoolID", 1));
```

[See example here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter)

Comment: So each value in the dropdown box (in the web app) will have to have a corresponding value for the call to sql?